# shell script regex help needed

Tags: regex, bash, shell

My file names are like this `F1616L_GATCAG_L002_R2_001`, and I want to extract the name before the first underscore `_`, in this case, `F1616L`.

I am a newbie to shell script regex, could someone help with this?

I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using BASH string manipulation:

```
s='F1616L_GATCAG_L002_R2_001'
echo "${s%%_*}"
F1616L
```

**UPDATE:** To get 2nd part after `_`:

```
[[ "$s" =~ ^[^_]+_([^_]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
GATCAG
```

Comment: how can I extract the part between the first "_" and the second "_"? In this case, how to get "GATCAG" ? Thanks

Comment: Ok sure see the update to get `extract the part between the first _ and the second _`